# How can I change the Background Color of my P element based off of the User Inputs? Looking for Green with discount Yellow Without

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the color of my P element with an id of result based off of what the user inputs into my prompts.

```
   </h1>
    <p id="item1"></p>
    <p id="item2"></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <h1>
```

```
let discount = 0;

if (total >= 100) {
    discount = 10;
} else if (total >= 50 || total < 100) {
    discount = 05;
} else {
    discount = 0;
} 

//Establish Grand Total
let grandTotal = total * discount / 100;

//Display results
if (discount > 0) {
    document.querySelector("#result").style.backgroundColor="green";
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = "Your total purchase is $" + grandTotal + " which includes your " + discount + "% discount.";
    document.querySelector("#result").style.color="white";
} else {
    document.querySelector("#result").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = "Your total purchase is $" + total;
    document.querySelector("#result").style.color="black";
}
```

Im not totally sure what I am doing wrong and can't seem to figure it out. All I would like is to make sure that whichever item costs they input based off of what I have written the P background color for the result will either show up green or yellow.. I got the green to work.

I tried a whole bunch of different things as well as used mdn docs and used my professors videos but he didn't explain on how to change the color based on input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet uses a few more advanced language features of ES5 and ES6, but it demonstrates how you can use less code and keep the script scalable (avoiding the use of `id` attributes):

```js
function calc(){
  const ttl=h1p.reduce((a,c)=>+c.textContent+a,0),disc=ttl<100?ttl<50?0:5:10;
  res.textContent=`Your total purchase is $${(ttl*(100-disc)/100).toFixed(2)}${disc?` which includes your ${disc}% discount`:""}.`;
  res.className=disc?`disc${disc}`:"";
}
const h1p=[...document.querySelectorAll("h1 p")], res=h1p.pop();

h1p.forEach(el=>{
 el.setAttribute("contenteditable","true")
 el.addEventListener("input",calc)
});
```

```css
h1 p {min-height:30px; min-width:100px; border :1px solid grey}
.disc5 {background-color:yellow}
.disc10{background-color:green; color:white}
```

```html
<h1>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</h1>
```

I made the `<p>` elements `contenteditable`, so they can act as "input" elements.